# React native can't send sms with Vonage Nexmo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sms, vonage

I am trying to send sms via Vonage Nexmo, I get this error:

> {"_bodyBlob": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "03232404-7668-4E97-ADB3-CC7D084EF6B3", "name": "api.txt", "offset": 0, "size": 49, "type": "application/json"}}, "_bodyInit": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "03232404-7668-4E97-ADB3-CC7D084EF6B3", "name": "api.txt", "offset": 0, "size": 49, "type": "application/json"}}, "bodyUsed": false, "headers": {"map": {"content-disposition": "attachment; filename="api.txt"", "content-length": "49", "content-type": "application/json", "date": "Mon, 17 Jan 2022 17:18:59 GMT", "server": "nginx", "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains", "x-content-type-options": "nosniff", "x-envoy-upstream-service-time": "1", "x-frame-options": "deny", "x-nexmo-trace-id": "57b091eb128ef3910815ecbbb0df9632", "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block;"}}, "ok": false, "status": 401, "statusText": "", "type": "default", "url": "https://api.nexmo.com/v1/messages"}

this is my fetch code:

```
const sendSms = (phone,message) =>{
            
            var url = ALL.NEXMO_URL;
            var bearer = ALL.NEXMO_TOKEN;
            fetch(url, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': bearer,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body:{
                        "api_key":ALL.NEXMO_API_KEY,
                        "api_secret":ALL.NEXMO_API_SECRET,
                        "message_type": "text",
                            "text": message,
                            "to": "XXX"+phone+"",
                            "from": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                            "channel": "sms",
                            "client_ref":"Jelivery"
                    }
                }).then(responseJson => {
                    console.log(responseJson);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });



        };
```

this is my consts define

```
export const NEXMO_URL = "https://api.nexmo.com/v1/messages";
export const NEXMO_TOKEN = "Basic ENCODED BASE 64==";
export const NEXMO_API_SECRET = "XXXXX";
export const NEXMO_API_KEY = "XXXXX";
```

**also**

I tried to install rpm install Nexmo ... react native can't recognize this module in node_modules.

any help please?

Comment: You don't need to send your nexmo API key and secret in the body of your request. The API is returning a 401 for unauthorised, which means your bearer token is not valid. How are you generating this token?

Comment: hi @abdulajet I changed my token, see my edit. and I get 422 error instead of 401

Comment: can you remove api_key and api_secret from your body